# Internet Not Accessible To Windows 10's Universal Apps

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

A problem I am facing from last 1 month. I have a Windows 10 Pro version 1511 Build 10586.71. I'm on a wifi connec. and internet is accessible to all desktop apps but not to universal apps. Windows Updates also aren't being downloaded. As soon as I click check for updates, it says:

[image]

Store also cant access internet. There's little exception: Mail app can access internet and sync mails. But store is completely off.

My int. connection is pretty good and there's no problem with it. I tried connecting to different wifi connection (e.g my phone's hotspot). Didn't work.

Plus there's always yellow sign there:

[image]

But the internet works properly. Please help.

Comment: look if DNS client service is running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved the problem by enabling few services I disabled just to see if I get more battery life. Don't know if DNS service was one of them